# Black Labyrinth or Tube it in Waitomo?

Tags: new-zealand, adventure, north-island

I have a few hours in Waitomo and I want to do a glowworm-tubing tour. I have seen two offers that seem to be good (unfortunately I won't have enough time for the longer ones):

- The Caveworld [Tube it](http://www.caveworld.co.nz/tubeit) Tour
- The Legendary Black Water Rafting [Black Labyrinth](http://www.waitomo.com/black-water-rafting/Pages/black-labyrinth.aspx) Tour

The main thing that entices me to go on one of these tours is tubing under the glow of the worms. I enjoy adrenaline-rush "adventure" stuff but as far as I can tell both of these tours are quite easy.

Which tour would you suggest for someone who wants the most jaw-dropping views of the caves on a tube?

Comment: I'd contact both and ask about the glow-worms. In my experience glow-worms are rather noise sensitive and visitors have to be well behaved and quiet to ensure that you get best results. I'd expect that unless special care was taken to ensure that quietness was maintained in appropriate areas that the glow-worm experience may be limited. But, I may be wrong :-).